# how can I read the registry from a service?

Tags: c#, .net, service, registry

I have a .net service which just started to fail - (meaning it will not start) when being installed.

**NOTE**: This is a 64 bit service

The recent changes I made were to perform a check for the .net framework version as shown in the Init function call.

Here is the service constructor:

```
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CanHandleSessionChangeEvent = true; //can't be called after service start !

        Init();
    }
```

This is where I am doing the check to find the .net framework version:

```
    private void Init()
    {
        try{
            string version = GetVersion();
            // check version here
        }catch(Exception ex){
            // log the error
        }
    }
```

GetVersion returns the .net version of the system where the service is running:
NOTE: this code comes from an MS web site

```
    private string GetVersion()
    {
        const string subkey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\";

        string retval = "0.0";

        using (RegistryKey ndpKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32).OpenSubKey(subkey))
        {
            if (ndpKey != null)
            {
                object obj = ndpKey.GetValue("Release");
                if( obj != null )
                {
                    retval = CheckFor45PlusVersion((int)obj);
                }                    
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(retval);
        return retval;
    }
```

this function simply does some number checking 
NOTE: this comes from an MS web site

```
    private string CheckFor45PlusVersion(int releaseKey)
    {
        if (releaseKey >= 461808)
            return "4.7.2";
        if (releaseKey >= 461308)
            return "4.7.1";
        if (releaseKey >= 460798)
            return "4.7";
        if (releaseKey >= 394802)
            return "4.6.2";
        if (releaseKey >= 394254)
            return "4.6.1";
        if (releaseKey >= 393295)
            return "4.6";
        if (releaseKey >= 379893)
            return "4.5.2";
        if (releaseKey >= 378675)
            return "4.5.1";
        if (releaseKey >= 378389)
            return "4.5";

        // This code should never execute. A non-null release key should mean that 4.5 or later is installed.
        return "4.0";
    }
```

**Point to ponder:**
Could this be due to the fact the service is a 64 bit service and I am requesting a 32 bit key?

```
    using (RegistryKey ndpKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32)
```

**EventViewer error**

this is the only error I get from the EventViewer

```
Product: Service1 -- Error 1923. Service 'Service1' (Service1) could not be installed.  Verify that you have sufficient privileges to install system services.
```

Comment: I don't see any exception handling. Could you add some and update the question with the exception details?

Comment: Whats with all the downvotes? Seems ok to me.

Comment: I have a try catch around the "GetVersion" and log it... but nothing is logged (it's not the code above... but it's in my production code )  I just added the try/catch for Crowcoder ...

Comment: What does "fail" mean for this application?

Comment: updated question

Comment: There must be an exception thrown. Is there anything in the Event Viewer?

Comment: A 64 bit service should have no problem reading 32 bit registry keys. So like other commented, check the actual exception/crash and it would easily tell what's wrong.

Comment: updated question with event viewer results - any more suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After about an hour of debugging... I changed:

```
 RegistryView.Registry32
```

to

```
 RegistryView.Registry64
```

and it worked.